# Is there a need of [scala-string] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I just saw that one of my old question was [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16046146/revisions) to add up the [scala-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-string) tag. I'm wondering if we actually need that tag ?

In my opinion a combination of `scala` and `string` tags should suffice. What is the communities opinion on this ?

Also if we go by similar logic of `scala-string`, then we can also have other tags such as `haskell-string`, `python-string` etc.

Comment: Editor seems obsessed with concatenation; [another example here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5482904).

Comment: Note that [c-string], [cstring] and [c-strings] should not be destroyed in this purge, as programs in other languages often have to work with C strings due to C's status as the lingua franca of cross-language interop.  (Though some uses of [cstring] actually refer to the MFC C++ class.  Cleanup?)